# Isometric tilemaps : manage the sorting layer of GameObjects attached to tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm working with an isometric tilemap to create some sort of city builder. I want my player to be able to create a building when he clicks on the tilemap, and I want that building to be a tile on that tilemap, so I created a Scriptable Tile (via 
`AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<BuildingTile>(), path);`) and set the tile's sprite with a random building sprite for testing purpose. And everything works fine !
[image: Works fine with sprites to tiles]

Note that here, I created the buildings from down-left to top-right.

Now, I want to attach a GameObject to it, which will hold all the behaviour of my building. So instead of applying the sprite to the tile, I apply it to the attached GameObject (because I plan to use some animations, which can't be applied to tiles). And that's where I'm in trouble : when the sprite is applied to the attached GameObject instead of the tile itself, the sorting is messed up :

[image: Doesn't work with sprites to GameObjects]

Again, it's drawn from bottom-left to top-right, if I do it in the opposite order, it displays well (so I guess the layer is determined by the creation order).

Is there a way to tell a tile "apply your sorting layer to your attached GameObject" ?

What I tried so far :
- Set my tilemap sort mode to "individual" instead of "Chunk". Does nothing.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html#customaxis  This should help ya  More specifically https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Isometric-CreateIso.html

Comment: Ok, yeah, I'm stupid. I already set the 0 1 0 transparency sort axis, but forgot to select the "Custom Axis" option in the select. I feel bad to receive a RTFM with a page I already read, but it's well deserved xD. Thank you !